# how to solve problems with relative paths when using htaccess file and multiple URL parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, relative-path

I have a problem with my URL, due to my htaccess file (i think) for making "pretty URLs".

Everything works like it should when I give a URL with one parameter like this:

```
localhost/project/page
```

But when I add another parameter at the end of the URL like this:

```
localhost/project/page/parameter
```

the page cannot find images, even though the path is absolutely the same and the second parameter in the URL is irrelevant for the page.

Here is my the content of my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

if you think the problem is occuring for some other reason, please let me know.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most common problem people face when switching to pretty URL schemes.

This problem is happening because you're using relative paths in your css/js/image paths. You have 2 options to fix this problem.

1. Use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
2. You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up using <base href='".MAINPATH."' />, where MAINPATH is a constant variable containing the absolute path for my project.